# Git Svn Password View/Reset?

Tags: passwords, git-svn

I have a personal learning project that I shelved for awhile but recently decided to get back into. After hearing so much about Git, I decided to give it a try. Thus far I've been able to initialize an empty Git repository but then it prompts me for a password of which I've misplaced. My first question, where is the password being prompted from? My assumption was SVN, so I've tried looking for a way to view or reset it but I haven't come across anything that seems to make sense in this scenario. Below is where I keep getting caught...

```
$ git svn fetch
me@myemail.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again
Connection closed by xx.xxx.xxx.xx (occurs on third attempt)
Network connection closed unexpectedly: Connection closed unexpectedly at /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1477
```

SVN Version: 1.4.4 (r25188)
Mac Version: 10.5.8

Currently, I'm the only one working on this project, so I'm open to suggestions drastic or otherwise, that would make collaborating in the future easier.

many thanks!
Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you've set up a password in your Subversion server. Depending on how exactly you've set up authentication for your Subversion repository, you may may need to look in the `conf/authz` and/or `conf/passwd` files in your Subversion repository. If you're using simple password authentication, your password will be in plaintext in the `conf/passwd` file. Otherwise, see the Subversion documentation to find out what you did.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything listed in conf/auth or /passwd. I'll take a look through the documentation, I must be overlooking something.

Comment: Thanks Greg - there were a couple issues on the server and my machine that needed to be sorted out.